# PSQL query with join query from a db newbie

Tags: sql, psql

I have two database tables. I'll simplify for the sake of this question

```
USERS
id : int
email: varchar

EVENTS:
user_id: int
event_name: varchar
```

I'd like to build a query that'll give me an output like:

```
ID      Email     Event name
------- --------- ----------------------
1        r@r.com  Test event 1
2        d@d.com  Test event 2
```

Obviously the query will select * from EVENTS but will also need to match the user_id in EVENTS via join I assume, to be able to select the e-mail in the USERS table corresponding to the id.

Any ideas how the syntax would look like?

Comment: This is a basic `join` query.  You should learn the basics of SQL if you want to use the language and databases effectively.

Comment: as I said, "db newbie"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  u.id AS ID,
  u.email AS Email,
  e.event_name AS Event
FROM
  users u JOIN events e ON u.id = e.event_id
```

SQL is best understood with potatoes: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/